# MySQL Failed to load adter Remote Connectivity Configuration

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon Cloud to deploy my web services. However, this requires a MySQL instance and I already installed it. In order to allow remote connectivity to MySQL database, I followed the below sequence as elaborated in MySQL documentation and even in the below thread.

Edit my.cnf file to change the following.

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = <server ip OR 0.0.0.0>
```

The same solutions discussed in detail, following posts.
[Remote Connections Mysql Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu)

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

However, as soon as I edited the my.cnf file as mentioned, the MySQL server failed to restart. I tried my best to recover this, it's failing instead.

Could anyone help me to identify and resolve the issue, would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that the MySQL server isn't running.

Try setting the bind-address to 0.0.0.0

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Verify that the files are deleted

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I think the issue occurred when I tried to edit the conf file while the service is running.