# Ip4address not working for node-mysql connection ubuntu

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am able to open phpmyadmin with both localhost as well as my IP4 address:

1. http://localhost/phpmyadmin
2. http://192.168.3.72/phpmyadmin
3. http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/

All the above Works

But when i try to apply IP4 address to this

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret'
});
```

Reference : https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#introduction

I get error as :

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Ports which are used are:**

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I tried with `netstat -nlt | grep 3306`

But i get blank output instead of :

```
mysqld  1046  mysql  10u  IPv4  5203  0t0  TCP  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 (LISTEN)
```

When tried with this post:
 [Remote Connections Mysql Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu)

But when tried with : `netstat -tulpn | grep :3306`

I get output as:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.3.72:3306       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Can anybody please assist with this...

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a MySQL client, it doesn't play any role in getting Node connected to the server. You have to configure MySQL Server to listen on external IP address, which you apparently haven't.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro - When i try from externally telnet: could not resolve 192.168.3.72:3306/telnet: Name or service not known. So may i know how to configure MySQL server plz

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote Connections Mysql Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve the problem :-)

1. I logged in as root using `sudo su`
2. Edited `subl /etc/mysql/my.cnf` & Replace bind-address with my IP4 address
3. Run :  `service mysql restart`

Finally it gave me result as:

```
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 12210
```

And now i am able to login successfully using IP4 address from external sources.

Thanks for all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost"?

Comment: `localhost` should resolve to `127.0.0.1`, but this may be worth a try.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 works for mysql connection as it is equivalent to localhost. But i want to share mysql db externally. I want to share it with my IP4 address itself in LAN right? Its not working :(

Comment: did you try "telnet 192.168.3.72:3306" from other computer in LAN? The problem can be 3306 port denied for remoting

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - Thanks for your replies. I edited my question with more clear info. Could you please check with the same if that helps in solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to connect to MySQL using the wrong port.  To find out what port MySQL is listening to you can do this:

**Windows** (from MySQL):
`mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';`

**Unix**:
`netstat -tln`

Once you have determined the correct port (which is 3306 by default), you can explicitly specify a port when you try to connect from Node:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  port: 3306
});
```