# Remote database xampp from other computer

Tags: sql, xampp, odbc, localhost, heidisql

I have sql database is running on xampp localhost,
how to open from another computer with heidiSQL or ODBC driver??

Comment: what SQL database is running on Localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access MySQL from another computer you have to configure the MySQL instance on your xampp box to allow remote connections, see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu/15684341#15684341)

Then you can go to the HiediSQL box and use the XAMPP boxes IP address to connect.

Hope that helps