# Cant connect to azure mysql database remotely

Tags: mysql, azure

I've created an azure mysql database, added my client IP to the firewall to allow it. I've added the ports 1433 and 3306 to both inbound and outbound exceptions to my windows firewall. I've opened both ports on my router. I am still unable to connect to my database using programs, such as workbench or toad. It gives me errors such as "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." Workbench gives the error "Lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0.  I know my information is all correct, because i know it is connecting. But something is denying my access. I've exhausted all google searches and nothing is solving the problem. If my connection info is correct and all IP's and ports are accounted for, what else could be the problem?

The strange thing is i can connect through visual studio. It's the only thing that will let me connect, however the interface to edit the mysql databse in visual studio is horrific. I cant even get it to work properly. Any ideas would be appreciated so that i can get connected from a decent mysql editor.

Comment: Any luck you've solved this? I have stumbled upon the same issue and do not want to use a VM.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu/15684341#15684341) and make sure your MySQL config is correct and your users are configured properly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In order to access the config file being discussed there, do i need to have the mysql databse on a virtual machine? I currently only have the mysql database by itself which i am trying to access. The whole point in this is to avoid the virtual machine. if i need a virtual machine i'll just go rent one. I was hoping to use azure for the mysql databse itself. I'm new to all this so maybe i'm just missing something. Can you not have an azure mysql databse without a virtual machine? Is there a way to access this config file through azure , or through an FTP of some kind? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do not need a VM. You need to make sure MySQL on Azure is able to accept remote connections and that your user is allowed to connect to that DB. Lastly you should take a look at the MySQL log info for more details about the connections being closed.