# What can be blocking remote login to MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, linux, server

I'm trying to set up a MySQL server. Its running on Ubuntu. When I try to log into it from local, via 'mysql -u user - h server-ip-add -p', it will ask for a password, and then time out after the password is entered. I'm able to SSH into the server, and then access mysql from there.

I've checked that port 3306 is open in the iptables settings:

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
f2b-nginx-http-auth  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  69.114.251.207       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-nginx-http-auth (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  181.211.20.46        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  5.238.99.64          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  93.82.51.144         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  91.197.232.103       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  90.150.180.36        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  78.243.95.82         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  61.91.245.98         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  5.140.148.242        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  5.104.107.139        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  31.28.97.115         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  31.163.250.245       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  31.162.171.190       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  223.99.174.194       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  223.229.249.84       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  222.74.225.125       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  222.220.35.196       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  222.171.242.151      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  218.56.106.106       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  218.3.140.74         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  202.163.79.110       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  195.162.95.35        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  195.154.36.75        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  191.80.83.249        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  188.187.52.223       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  185.136.151.107      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  185.116.157.105      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  181.20.73.164        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  177.43.247.139       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  177.19.185.235       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  171.35.163.238       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  123.31.31.146        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  123.31.31.140        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  123.168.209.238      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  122.189.199.143      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  119.193.140.162      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  119.177.250.2        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  116.31.116.41        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  116.16.69.191        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  115.213.198.13       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  113.195.145.21       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  103.217.90.10        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  103.207.37.24        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
ufw-user-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
ufw-not-local  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

On line 217, I see that port 3306 is open:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
```

Also, I made sure that the local IP I'm trying to log in from is tied to 'user':

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+----------------+
| User             | Host           |
+------------------+----------------+
| alex             | 6x.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| alex             | localhost      |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost      |
| mysql.sys        | localhost      |
| root             | localhost      |
+------------------+----------------+
```

Does anyone know what I may be missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can find your question answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wildcard(%) entry for your user.Maybe it will work cause in my case
 SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
 command gives same result as yours just one wildcard entry is  more and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

I established that it was a firewall issue. I enabled all connections from my local IP to this server, and it's working correctly now. It's important to add your IP to the top of the list in the INPUT section of iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT`
```