# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.5' (111)

Tags: ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, mysql-5.7, mysql-error-2003

I have two ubuntu VMs in azure. Both are **Ubuntu 17.10** On is for database and the other for web. The database has **mysql 5.7** set up. I have been trying to connect from the web server to db server.

I tried

```
mysql -h 10.0.0.5
```

and got

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.5' (111)

I have also tried running the same line from db server. I see the same output. However it does work like this within the db server:

```
mysql -uroot
```

And it also works like this:

```
mysql -h localhost
```

I have looked at several online solutions about this issue. Mostly the solution is to uncomment `bind-address` line my.cnf. However I don't find this line. I have tried adding the line `bind-address = 10.0.0.5`, but that crashes the mysql.

Note that I am able to ping from web server to db server.

Comment: Have you set a password for the `root` user?

Comment: nop. `mysql -uroot` logs into mysql. also i have tested invalid passwords. it shows a different error.

Comment: Try to use the *real* IP address of the server not the virtual to check if it responds

Comment: tried with the public ip. doesn't respond. its just stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the steps mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu)

- set `bind-address` on `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
- restart `mysql` server
- check if it listens on the defined address
- create a user for the remote connection
- grant the privilages
- flush privilages