# No able to connect remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to connect on my mysql database when I'm not on localhost - on localhost it's working. Everytime I wish to connect, I don't have any error, but only a timeout exec...

Here is what I've done so far

- create a user on mysql who can access to any hosts("%")
- purge the iptables
- my port 3306 is opened (see screenshot)
- the bind-address line is 0.0.0.0 in the mysqld.cnf file - I even tried to put in it comment -  please note my.cnf sends to the mysqld.cnf file.
- of course for every modification I've restarted the mysql server - and the server itself...
- no firewall are setup...

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, mysql and phpmyadmin are setup on it.

What I'm missing ? 
Thank you for your help
Bastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you changed the bind address you restarted with `systemctl restart mysql.service`, yes?

Here's a very similar situation, try following all of these steps:  [Remote Connections Mysql Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu)

I think the flush privileges step will be a help to you.

Comment: Yep ! It works - very very weird ! But thanks so much :)